# Gossiping or engaging in gossip(if present continuous must be used)

Tags: grammar, present-continuous, collocations

Let's say you were asked about a thing you prefer doing over the other. And you say:

> ''I would choose to be reading books rather than [gossiping](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/gossiping) about people's lives.''

OR

> ''I would choose to be reading books rather than **engaging in gossip** about people's lives.''

I have 2 things on my mind:

- 1) using the ''**gossiping**'' word in a sentence seems a bit off(never heard of it). Am I right?
- 2) if the ''**gossiping**'' word is appropriate to use, I wanted to advance it by changing it into ''**engaging in gossip**''(colloquial) to make me sound like a native, as part of stepping it up a bit as an ESL.

Comment: If you google **gossping**, you will find it well established. And while changing it to **engaging in gossip** is quite legitimate, it is unlikely to make you sound better educated or more idiomatic.

Comment: I think your question boils down to whether [*gossip*](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/gossip) can be used as a verb. It can, and you could've checked the dictionary to find that out. The linked dictionary entry provides some collocations when it's used as a noun as well.

Comment: @userr2684291, I think you're missing the point here. I've already looked that up on the site, but still, human experiences cannot be compared to just computer inputs.

Comment: I think it sounds most natural and colloquial to use the first version with **gossiping**.  As a general rule, if you can use fewer words without changing the meaning, you'll sound more natural.